# Primitive and continuity

Tags: integration, analysis

I have that $$-(p(t) u'(t))'=f(t,u)$$ where $f:[0,+\infty)\times\mathbb{R}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is continuous

i want to prove that $p(t) u'(t)$ is continuous! for this i do the primitive of the two sides

$$p(t) u'(t)=\int_t^{+\infty} f(s,u(s)) ds$$ and my question is

is $\int_t^{+\infty} f(s,u(s)) ds$ is continuous ?

Please Thank you .

Comment: If $(p(t) u'(t))'$ exits forall $t$ then $p(t) u'(t)$ must be continuous.

Comment: we don't use the continuity of f ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're hoping to prove that a certain function is continuous. It's known to be differentiable (because you have a formula for its derivative). There's a basic theorem that says that if $g$ is differentiable at $x$, then $g$ is continuous at $x$. That theorem, applied for every $t$ in your domain, proves the thing you wanted.

Addition: The theorem doesn't seem to have a name (it's Theorem 1 in Chapter 9 of Spivak's *Calculus*), but here's the statement/proof for your amusement:

Theorem: If $f$ is differentiable at $a$, then $f$ is continuous at $a$.

Proof: 
\begin{align}
\lim_{h \to 0} f(a + h) - f(a) &=\lim_{h \to 0} \frac{f(a + h) - f(a)}{h} \cdot  h \\
&=\lim_{h \to 0} \frac{f(a + h) - f(a)}{h} \cdot \lim_{h \to 0} h \\
&= f'(a) \cdot 0\\
&=0. 
\end{align}

Since $\lim_{h \to 0} f(a + h) - f(a) = 0$, we can add $f(a)$ to both sides to get 
$\lim_{h \to 0} f(a + h) = f(a)$, which means that $f$ is continuous at $a$.

Comment: what is the name of this theorem please

Comment: See edits in answer above.